# how to insert a list in rdf

Tags: rdf, sesame, openrdf

I have a graph, and in this graph I have a list like this:

```
:Michelangelo       :representativeFor :Italy;
                rdfs:label "Michelangelo di Ludovico Buonarroti Simoni";
                :birthInfo [:date "1475-03-10"^^xsd:date; :place  :Florence];
                :sculptorOf [a rdf:List; rdf:first :Pieta; rdf:rest [a rdf:List; rdf:first :David; rdf:rest [a rdf:List; rdf:first :TheLastJudgement; rdf:rest rdf:nil]]];
:sculptorOf rdfs:domain :Sculptor; rdfs:range :Sculpture.
```

When I put this query

```
select * 
where {:David a ?z}
```

I expect to get resourse and Sculpture.
I don't understand why is not working , what should I do ?

Comment: Your data example is invalid (specifically the list as you wrote it is not legal RDF), you could never have added this to a Sesame store without an error. This makes it very unclear what you're trying to do or where exactly the problem is. Please correct your example to show the data you're _actually_ inserting, the exact query you use, the expected result, and the actual result.

Comment: I edited and I put exactly what I added in Sesame. What I posted earlier was me trying to fix the problem @JeenBroekstra

Answer (score 3):

Your title is **how to insert a list in rdf**, but it looks like you're trying to query where your values in the query are in the list in the data.

If I understand you correctly, you want to find David's types based on:

```
:Michelangelo :sculptorOf [a rdf:List;
                           rdf:first :Pieta; 
                           rdf:rest [a rdf:List;
                                     rdf:first :David;
                                     rdf:rest [a rdf:List;
                                               rdf:first :TheLastJudgement;
                                               rdf:rest rdf:nil]]];
```

and the domain and range axioms:

```
:sculptorOf rdfs:domain :Sculptor; rdfs:range :Sculpture.
```

This isn't how RDF and OWL work.  Michaelangelo didn't sculpt a list of things, he sculpted different things.  In RDF, you'd represent this as:

```
:Michelangelo :sculptorOf  :Pieta, :David, :TheLastJudgement .
```

That's shorthand for three triples:

```
:Michelangelo :sculptorOf  :Pieta .
:Michelangelo :sculptorOf  :David .
:Michelangelo :sculptorOf  :TheLastJudgement .
```

Now, if you have OWL inference enabled, you'll be able to infer that since **David** is the object of a **sculptorOf** assertion, **David** must have the type **Sculpture**.  If RDF(S) inference is available, you'll also be able to infer that **David** is an **rdfs:Resource**.

Comment: Actually I have used that list for sculptures , because I am interested in their position. The sculptures are placed in the list in the order of their creation. It is any possibility to use a list and still set up their range? @Joshua